# Calling Constructor Multiple times

Tags: java

How to call the Constructor multiple times using the same object

```
class a
{

    a(int i)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        a b = new a();
        int x = 10;
        while( x > 0)
        {
            //Needed to pass the x value to constructor muliple times
        }
    }
}
```

I needed to pass the parameter to that constructor.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Having multiple instances of class a or printing value of variable 'i' multiple times?

Comment: This is clearly an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Tell us what you are trying to achieve and why you think calling the constructor more than once would be useful.

Comment: `while( x > 0)
        {
            b = new a(x--);
        }`

Answer (score 2):

**Constructor of a `class A` constructs the objects of `class A`.**

Construction of an object happens only once, and after that you can modify the state of the object using methods (functions).

Also notice if programmer does not write any constructor in his class then the Java compiler puts the constructor for the class `(public constructor without any parameters)` on its own.

In the case where a constructor has been provided by the programmer, the compiler does not create a default constructor. It assumes, the programmer knows and wants creation of the objects of his/her class as per the signature of the explicit constructor.

Constructor calls are chained. Suppose there exists below class relationship.

`Child.java extends Parent.java and Parent.java extends GrandParent.java`.

Now if `Child child = new Child();` is done, only one object is created and that is of `Child.java`, but the object also has all of the features of `GrandParent` first then with the features of the `Parent` and then the `Child`.

Hence first constructor of `GrandParent.java` is called then `Parent.java` is called and lastly the constructor of `Child.java` is called.

> Constructors are special and different from other methods.

**The intent of constructors is to create the object**, so each time you use the `new` operator, the constructor is called and a **new object** is created. You can not call the constructor directly. You need the new operator to call it. Even if you see some class defining methods like `getInstance()`, it still uses the `new` operator to construct the object and return the created object.

*PS there are ways to create an object without calling constructor (like Serialization) but that is out of context of the discussion here.

Comment: I wanted to use the constructor like methods and thats the reason to reuse the constructor  multiple times.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please see the intent of as why Constructors were included in the language. If you call constructor (using new) multiple times you will create as many different new objects as you the times you call the constructor.

Comment: @Rajesh did the posts here (including others and mine) helped you to get the concepts and intent of constructors or still you have some queries. I suggest you to read all the comments and answers we have posted, unserstand the concept as what is the intent of constructor and merhods. Apply right tool to solve your problem, (like mentioned above do not make the problem a XY problem)

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are called only once at the time of the creation of the object.

Can you please be specific about what you want to achieve?

But I think you could try one of the following two things.

**Calling the constructor to create a new object and assigning it to the object 'b':**

```
b = new a(1);
```

**Using the setter method:**

```
void setI(int i){
     this.i = i;
}

b.setI(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int x = 10;
    while( x > 0)
    {
        a b = new a(x);
    }
```